# Dice probability question?

Tags: probability

I just don't get this, could you show method and answer please? Thank you

Two dice are thrown simultaneously. The scores are to be multipled. Denoting by P(n) the probability that the number n will be obtained.

Calculate:

a. P(9)

b. P(4)

d. P(35)

e. Given that P(t) = 1/9, find the possible values of t

Comment: a) We can only get this in one way, $3$ on the red and $3$ on the green. b) We can get this in three ways, $(1,4),(4,1),(2,2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability for obtaining $1,...,6$ for each dice is $1/6$ (we have $6$ different possible results for one dice). For two dices, we have a total of $6\times6=36$ possibilities (form obtaining the $1,1$ to the $6,6$). Then, the probability for a given result of the dice 1 and the dice 2 is $1/36$.

a) The only way for obtaining the $9$ is to obtain $3$ in the first dice and $3$ in the second one. Then: $P(9)=1/36$

b) There are $3$ ways for obtaining $4$: $(2,2)$, $(4,1)$ and $(1,4)$ (the numbers represent the result of the first and the second dice, respectivelly). Then, the probability is $P(4)=3/36=1/12$.

I guess you can follow the same reasoning for the rest of the cases. Just try by your own, and let me know if you get further problems!